# Encryption not working with key generated from openssl for AES-256

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes, sha1

I have generated a key using OpenSSL for AES-256. Below is the line I am executing:

```
openssl enc -aes-256 -cbc -k Secret_key -P -md sha1 > FILE_NAME.txt
```

It is generating a key of 64 bytes/characters. When I try encrypting data using this key then I get an error:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 64 bytes

I am not sure how to use the key generated and also whether the key generated is correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key for AES-256 should be 32-bytes long. Most likely it is hex-encoded on output.